# Iterate over an array or object with underscore

Tags: backbone.js, properties, underscore.js

Why title return null !! , is there any confusion with anything !

Here  is my code

```
_.each(collection.models, function(element, index, list){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(element)); //{"title":"Dipped Bunny Blossom","id":49,"created_at":"2015-03-24T10:16:17Z","updated_at":"2015-03-24T13:56:12Z","type":"simple","status":"publish","downloadable":false,"virtual":false,"permalink":"http://beta-it.com/ticarttest/shop/dipped-bunny-blossom/","sku":"","price":"50.00","regular_price":"50.00","sale_price":null,"price_html":"<span class=\"amount\">&#36;50.00</span>","taxable":false,"tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","managing_stock":false,"stock_quantity":0,"in_stock":true,"backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"purchaseable":true,"featured":true,"visible":true,"catalog_visibility":"visible","on_sale":false,"weight":"1.00","dimensions":{"length":"50","width":"50","height":"50","unit":"cm"},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":null,"description":"","short_description":"","reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"4.50","rating_count":2,"related_ids":[34,43,45,47,120],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"categories":["BIRTHDAY","BUSINESS GIFTS","DIPPED FRUIT"],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":50,"created_at":"2015-03-03T10:16:10Z","updated_at":"2015-03-03T10:16:10Z","src":"http://beta-it.com/ticarttest/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dipped-Bunny-Blossom.jpg","title":"Dipped-Bunny-Blossom","alt":"","position":0}],"featured_src":"http://beta-it.com/ticarttest/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dipped-Bunny-Blossom.jpg","attributes":[],"downloads":[],"download_limit":0,"download_expiry":0,"download_type":"","purchase_note":"","total_sales":1,"variations":[],"parent":[]}
         console.log(element.id); // return 49 ok
         console.log(element.title); //return null !!!!

        // We are looping through the returned models from the remote REST API
        // Implement your custom logic here
    });
```

Comment: Is `collection` a backbone collection?

Comment: Yes  the collection a backbone collection

Comment: Models have `id` as a *property* (i.e. `model.id`) and as an *attribute* (i.e. `model.get('id')`), the other *attributes* are just attributes (i.e. `model.get('title')`).

Comment: What about my case ! i want to use element object  , how can extract it  ex element.get('title') ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a backbone collection, your code should look more like this:

```
collection.each(function(model) {
    console.log(model.attributes);
    console.log(model.id);
    console.log(model.get('title'));
});
```

Most attributes in backbone models must be accessed using the [`get` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get). `id` is a [special case](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) that can be accessed via `get` or as a direct `id` property. According to the docs:

> If you set the id in the attributes hash, it will be copied onto the model as a direct property.